# Unable to create application : java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android

Here the classes:

VoiceApplication class
used to initialize the database on first startup and to provide the ID of the mode when it was inserted, I've get this code from the gitorious and modified it.

```
 public class VoiceApplication extends Application {
    private static final String TAG = "VoiceAuth";

    private static final String PREF_KEY_MODE_ID = "modeId";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        initAuthMethod();
    }

    /**
     * Returns the unique ID of this authentication mode that was returned when 
     * this authentication mode was first inserted into the database.
     * @return
     */
    public long getModeId() {
        return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).getLong(PREF_KEY_MODE_ID, -1);
    }

    private void initAuthMethod() {
        if (!voiceAuthMethodExists()) {
            createAuthMethod();
        }
    }

    private void createAuthMethod() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Creating auth method with values: " + ContentValueDefaults.DEFAULT_CONTENT_VALUES.toString());
        Uri insertedUri = getContentResolver().insert(Mode.CONTENT_URI, ContentValueDefaults.DEFAULT_CONTENT_VALUES);
        long modeId = ContentUris.parseId(insertedUri);
        Log.v(TAG, "Storing modeId in preferences: " + modeId);
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        prefs.edit().putLong(PREF_KEY_MODE_ID, modeId).commit();
    }

    private boolean voiceAuthMethodExists() {
        String[] projection = {
                Mode.NAME
        };
        String selection = Mode.NAME + " = ?";
        String[] selectionArgs = {
                ContentValueDefaults.UNIQUE_NAME
        };
        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(Mode.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);

        if (!c.moveToFirst()) 
            return false;

        String existingName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Mode.NAME));

        return ContentValueDefaults.UNIQUE_NAME.equals(existingName);
    }

}
```

ContentValueDefaults class used for initializing the database

```
public final class ContentValueDefaults {

    public static final String MODE_TYPE = AuthModes.VOICE_RECOGNITION;
    public static final String UNIQUE_NAME = "com.neu.val.activity.VoiceAuthenticator";
    public static final String DISPLAY_NAME = "Voice Authentication";

    public static ContentValues DEFAULT_CONTENT_VALUES;

    static {
        DEFAULT_CONTENT_VALUES = new ContentValues();
        DEFAULT_CONTENT_VALUES.put(Mode.NAME, UNIQUE_NAME);
        DEFAULT_CONTENT_VALUES.put(Mode.TYPE, MODE_TYPE);
        DEFAULT_CONTENT_VALUES.put(Mode.DISPLAY_NAME, DISPLAY_NAME);
        DEFAULT_CONTENT_VALUES.put(Mode.PACKAGE_NAME, "com.neu.val.activity");
        DEFAULT_CONTENT_VALUES.put(Mode.CLASS_NAME, ".VoiceAuthenticator.java");
    }
}
```

VoiceAuthenticator class verifies the entered password for the user with the saved one, or redirects to the password creation activity if no password exists yet

```
public class VoiceAuthenticator extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private static final int MAX_DURATION = 2500;
    public static final String TAG = "VoiceAuth";
    private static final double THRESHOLD = 10000;
    private int seconds, progressTime;
    private Uri userUri;

    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private Button btnStartRecording, btnCancel;

    private WaveRecorder waveRecorder;

    public FeatureVector userFeatureVector;

    private static File outputFile = 
            new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC), 
                    "recording.wav");

    private Timer timer;
    private boolean stopped;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.voiceauth); 
       userUri = getIntent().getData();

        // this just for testing
        if (userUri == null) {
            finish();
            return;
        }
        if (!checkUserStillExists()) {
            UIUtils.showErrorDialog(
                    this,
                    "User deleted",
                    "The requested user does not exist anymore, authentication will not be possible!",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            finish();
                        }
                    });
            return;
        }
        checkFeaturesExist();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private boolean checkUserStillExists() {
        Cursor c = managedQuery(userUri, null, null, null, null);
        return c.getCount() > 0;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void checkFeaturesExist() {
        long userId = ContentUris.parseId(userUri);
        long modeId = ((VoiceApplication) getApplication()).getModeId();
        Uri featuresUri = Feature.buildFeaturesForSubjectAndMode(userId, modeId);
        Cursor c = managedQuery(featuresUri, null, null, null, null);
        if (c.getCount() == 0) {
            askToCreateFeatures();
        } else {
            setupUi();
        }
    }

    public void startProgress() { 
        final Handler handler = new Handler();

        TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            progress();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(timerTask, 1, 1000);
    }
    public void progress() {
        if (!stopped) // call ui only when the progress is not stopped
        {
            if (progressTime < MAX_DURATION) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            progressTime = progressBar.getProgress() + 1000;
                            progressBar.setProgress(progressTime);
                            seconds += 1000;
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
                stopRecord();
            }
        }
    }


    private void askToCreateFeatures() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Unknown user");
        builder.setMessage("No voice features for this user yet, do you want to record features now?");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(VoiceAuthenticator.this, CreateVoiceSample.class);
                long userId = ContentUris.parseId(userUri);
                intent.putExtra(Extras.EXTRA_USER_ID, userId);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                finish();
            }
        });
        builder.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                finish();
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }

    /**
     * Loads user info from the content resolver and sets up button listener.
     */
    private void setupUi() {
        btnStartRecording = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSpeak);
        btnCancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bCancel);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        progressBar.setMax(MAX_DURATION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.bSpeak:
            startRecording();
            checkResults();
            break;
        case R.id.bCancel:
            finish();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    private void startRecording() {
        seconds = 1000;
        progressTime = 0;
        progressBar.setProgress(0);
        if (outputFile.exists()) outputFile.delete();
        btnStartRecording.setEnabled(false);

        waveRecorder = new WaveRecorder(8000);
        waveRecorder.setOutputFile(outputFile.getAbsolutePath());
        stopped = false;
        try {
            waveRecorder.prepare();
            waveRecorder.start();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Recording started ... ",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void stopRecord() {
        stopped = true;
        waveRecorder.stop();
        waveRecorder.release();
        waveRecorder.reset();
        timer.cancel();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Recording stopped..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        startProgress();
        checkResults();
    }

    private void checkResults() {
        Cursor allCodebooksCursor = queryAllCodebooks();
        long claimedUserId = ContentUris.parseId(userUri);
        long bestUserId = -1;
        Log.i(TAG, "Starting to check voice features for userId=" + claimedUserId);

        double minAverageDistortion = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        if (allCodebooksCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                long currentUserId = allCodebooksCursor.getLong(allCodebooksCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Feature.SUBJECT_ID));
                Codebook codebook = getCodebookForUser(allCodebooksCursor);
                double averageDistortion = ClusterUtil.calculateAverageDistortion(
                        userFeatureVector, codebook);

                Log.d(TAG, "Calculated avg distortion for userId " + currentUserId + " =" + averageDistortion);
                if (averageDistortion < minAverageDistortion) {
                    minAverageDistortion = averageDistortion;
                    bestUserId = currentUserId;
                }
            } while (allCodebooksCursor.moveToNext());
        }

        if (minAverageDistortion <= THRESHOLD && claimedUserId == bestUserId) {
            returnSuccess(minAverageDistortion);
        } else {
            returnFailure();
        }
    }

    private Codebook getCodebookForUser(Cursor cursor) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String representation = cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(Feature.REPRESENTATION));
        Codebook codebook = gson.fromJson(representation,
                Codebook.class);
        return codebook;
    }

    private Cursor queryAllCodebooks() {
        long modeId = ((VoiceApplication) getApplication()).getModeId();
        Uri uri = Feature.buildFeaturesForMode(modeId);
        String[] columns = {
                Feature.SUBJECT_ID,
                Feature.REPRESENTATION
        };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, columns, null, null, null);
        return cursor;
    }

    private void returnFailure() {
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
        resultIntent.putExtra(Extras.EXTRA_RESULT, false);
        resultIntent.putExtra(Extras.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIDENCE, 0.0d);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
        finish();
    }

    private void returnSuccess(double minAverageDistortion) {
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
        resultIntent.putExtra(Extras.EXTRA_RESULT, true);
        resultIntent.putExtra(Extras.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIDENCE, minAverageDistortion);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
        finish();
    }

    class MfccTask extends AsyncTask<String, Object, FeatureVector> {

        private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        private final Activity parentActivity;

        public MfccTask(Activity parentActivity) {
            this.parentActivity = parentActivity;
        }

        @Override
        protected FeatureVector doInBackground(String... params) {
            String filename = params[0];
            WavReader wavReader = new WavReader(filename);

            Log.i(TAG, "Starting to read from file " + filename);
            double[] samples = readSamples(wavReader);

            Log.i(TAG, "Starting to calculate MFCC");
            double[][] mfcc = calculateMfcc(samples);

            FeatureVector pl = createFeatureVector(mfcc);

            return pl;
        }


        private FeatureVector createFeatureVector(double[][] mfcc) {
            int vectorSize = mfcc[0].length;
            int vectorCount = mfcc.length;
            Log.i(TAG, "Creating pointlist with dimension=" + vectorSize + ", count=" + vectorCount);
            FeatureVector pl = new FeatureVector(vectorSize, vectorCount);
            for (int i = 0; i < vectorCount; i++) {
                pl.add(mfcc[i]);
            }
            Log.d(CreateVoiceSample.TAG, "Added all MFCC vectors to pointlist");
            return pl;
        }

        private short createSample(byte[] buffer) {
            short sample = 0;
            // hardcoded two bytes here
            short b1 = buffer[0];
            short b2 = buffer[1];
            b2 <<= 8;
            sample = (short) (b1 | b2);
            return sample;
        }

        private double[][] calculateMfcc(double[] samples) {
            MFCC mfccCalculator = new MFCC(Constants.SAMPLERATE, Constants.WINDOWSIZE,
                    Constants.COEFFICIENTS, false, Constants.MINFREQ + 1, Constants.MAXFREQ, Constants.FILTERS);

            int hopSize = Constants.WINDOWSIZE / 2;
            int mfccCount = (samples.length / hopSize) - 1;
            double[][] mfcc = new double[mfccCount][Constants.COEFFICIENTS];
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            for (int i = 0, pos = 0; pos < samples.length - hopSize; i++, pos += hopSize) {
                mfcc[i] = mfccCalculator.processWindow(samples, pos);
                if (i % 20 == 0) {
                    publishProgress("Calculating features...", i, mfccCount);
                }
            }
            publishProgress("Calculating features...", mfccCount, mfccCount);

            Log.i(TAG, "Calculated " + mfcc.length + " vectors of MFCCs in "
                    + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + "ms");
            return mfcc;
        }

        private double[] readSamples(WavReader wavReader) {
            int sampleSize = wavReader.getFrameSize();
            int sampleCount = wavReader.getPayloadLength() / sampleSize;
            int windowCount = (int) Math.floor(sampleCount / Constants.WINDOWSIZE);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[sampleSize];
            double[] samples = new double[windowCount
                                          * Constants.WINDOWSIZE];

            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < samples.length; i++) {
                    wavReader.read(buffer, 0, sampleSize);
                    samples[i] = createSample(buffer);

                    if (i % 1000 == 0) {
                        publishProgress("Reading samples...", i, samples.length);
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(CreateVoiceSample.TAG, "Exception in reading samples", e);
            }
            return samples;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(FeatureVector result) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            userFeatureVector = result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(parentActivity);
            progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            progressDialog.setTitle("Working...");
            progressDialog.setMessage("Working...");
            progressDialog.setProgress(0);
            progressDialog.setMax(10000);
            progressDialog.show();
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Object... values) {
            String msg = (String) values[0];
            Integer current = (Integer) values[1];
            Integer max = (Integer) values[2];

            progressDialog.setMessage(msg);
            progressDialog.setProgress(current);
            progressDialog.setMax(max);
        }

    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.neu.val.activity"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
        android:name=".VoiceApplication">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".CreateVoiceSample"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.INSERT" />

                <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.hgb.feature" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DEFAULT" />

                <category android:name="com.neu.val.activity.CREATEVOICESAMPLE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".VoiceAuthenticator"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="com.neu.val.intent.AUTH_METHOD" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.neu.val.intent.DO_AUTH.voicerecognition"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name="com.neu.val.service.LockService" >
        </service>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.neu.val.service.BootStartUpReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <provider
            android:name="com.neu.val.database.AuthDb"
            android:authorities="com.neu.val.database">
        </provider>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and the logcat

```
  01-31 15:18:08.159: D/AndroidRuntime(9582): Shutting down VM
01-31 15:18:08.159: W/dalvikvm(9582): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41c72da0)
01-31 15:18:08.159: E/AndroidRuntime(9582): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-31 15:18:08.159: E/AndroidRuntime(9582): Process: com.neu.val.activity, PID: 9582
01-31 15:18:08.159: E/AndroidRuntime(9582): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.neu.val.activity.VoiceApplication: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-31 15:18:08.159: E/AndroidRuntime(9582):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4752)
01-31 15:18:08.159: E/AndroidRuntime(9582):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:172)
01-31 15:18:08.159: E/AndroidRuntime(9582):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1368)
01-31 15:18:08.159: E/AndroidRuntime(9582):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-31 15:18:08.159: E/AndroidRuntime(9582):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
01-31 15:18:08.159: E/AndroidRuntime(9582):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
01-31 15:18:08.159: E/AndroidRuntime(9582):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-31 15:18:08.159: E/AndroidRuntime(9582):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-31 15:18:08.159: E/AndroidRuntime(9582):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
01-31 15:18:08.159: E/AndroidRuntime(9582):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
01-31 15:18:08.159: E/AndroidRuntime(9582):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-31 15:18:08.159: E/AndroidRuntime(9582): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-31 15:18:08.159: E/AndroidRuntime(9582):     at com.neu.val.activity.VoiceApplication.voiceAuthMethodExists(VoiceApplication.java:78)
01-31 15:18:08.159: E/AndroidRuntime(9582):     at com.neu.val.activity.VoiceApplication.initAuthMethod(VoiceApplication.java:54)
01-31 15:18:08.159: E/AndroidRuntime(9582):     at com.neu.val.activity.VoiceApplication.onCreate(VoiceApplication.java:41)
01-31 15:18:08.159: E/AndroidRuntime(9582):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1013)
01-31 15:18:08.159: E/AndroidRuntime(9582):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4749)
01-31 15:18:08.159: E/AndroidRuntime(9582):     ... 10 more
01-31 15:18:09.989: I/Process(9582): Sending signal. PID: 9582 SIG: 9
01-31 15:18:10.099: D/AndroidRuntime(9705): Shutting down VM
01-31 15:18:10.099: W/dalvikvm(9705): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41c72da0)
01-31 15:18:10.099: E/AndroidRuntime(9705): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-31 15:18:10.099: E/AndroidRuntime(9705): Process: com.neu.val.activity, PID: 9705
01-31 15:18:10.099: E/AndroidRuntime(9705): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.neu.val.activity.VoiceApplication: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-31 15:18:10.099: E/AndroidRuntime(9705):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4752)
01-31 15:18:10.099: E/AndroidRuntime(9705):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:172)
01-31 15:18:10.099: E/AndroidRuntime(9705):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1368)
01-31 15:18:10.099: E/AndroidRuntime(9705):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-31 15:18:10.099: E/AndroidRuntime(9705):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
01-31 15:18:10.099: E/AndroidRuntime(9705):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
01-31 15:18:10.099: E/AndroidRuntime(9705):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-31 15:18:10.099: E/AndroidRuntime(9705):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-31 15:18:10.099: E/AndroidRuntime(9705):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
01-31 15:18:10.099: E/AndroidRuntime(9705):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
01-31 15:18:10.099: E/AndroidRuntime(9705):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-31 15:18:10.099: E/AndroidRuntime(9705): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-31 15:18:10.099: E/AndroidRuntime(9705):     at com.neu.val.activity.VoiceApplication.voiceAuthMethodExists(VoiceApplication.java:78)
01-31 15:18:10.099: E/AndroidRuntime(9705):     at com.neu.val.activity.VoiceApplication.initAuthMethod(VoiceApplication.java:54)
01-31 15:18:10.099: E/AndroidRuntime(9705):     at com.neu.val.activity.VoiceApplication.onCreate(VoiceApplication.java:41)
01-31 15:18:10.099: E/AndroidRuntime(9705):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1013)
01-31 15:18:10.099: E/AndroidRuntime(9705):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4749)
01-31 15:18:10.099: E/AndroidRuntime(9705):     ... 10 more
01-31 15:18:12.029: D/AndroidRuntime(9921): Shutting down VM
01-31 15:18:12.029: W/dalvikvm(9921): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41c72da0)
01-31 15:18:12.029: E/AndroidRuntime(9921): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-31 15:18:12.029: E/AndroidRuntime(9921): Process: com.neu.val.activity, PID: 9921
01-31 15:18:12.029: E/AndroidRuntime(9921): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.neu.val.activity.VoiceApplication: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-31 15:18:12.029: E/AndroidRuntime(9921):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4752)
01-31 15:18:12.029: E/AndroidRuntime(9921):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:172)
01-31 15:18:12.029: E/AndroidRuntime(9921):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1368)
01-31 15:18:12.029: E/AndroidRuntime(9921):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-31 15:18:12.029: E/AndroidRuntime(9921):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
01-31 15:18:12.029: E/AndroidRuntime(9921):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
01-31 15:18:12.029: E/AndroidRuntime(9921):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-31 15:18:12.029: E/AndroidRuntime(9921):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-31 15:18:12.029: E/AndroidRuntime(9921):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
01-31 15:18:12.029: E/AndroidRuntime(9921):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
01-31 15:18:12.029: E/AndroidRuntime(9921):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-31 15:18:12.029: E/AndroidRuntime(9921): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-31 15:18:12.029: E/AndroidRuntime(9921):     at com.neu.val.activity.VoiceApplication.voiceAuthMethodExists(VoiceApplication.java:78)
01-31 15:18:12.029: E/AndroidRuntime(9921):     at com.neu.val.activity.VoiceApplication.initAuthMethod(VoiceApplication.java:54)
01-31 15:18:12.029: E/AndroidRuntime(9921):     at com.neu.val.activity.VoiceApplication.onCreate(VoiceApplication.java:41)
01-31 15:18:12.029: E/AndroidRuntime(9921):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1013)
01-31 15:18:12.029: E/AndroidRuntime(9921):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4749)
01-31 15:18:12.029: E/AndroidRuntime(9921):     ... 10 more
01-31 15:18:13.849: I/Process(9921): Sending signal. PID: 9921 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Error is in voiceAuthMethodExists method line number 78. Can you tell whats that line?

Comment: if (!c.moveToFirst())                                                               return false;

Comment: Check if  **"c"** is not null

Comment: what do you mean @Rami

Comment: still it does not work .

Comment: The issue is with the cursor c being null and @Rami gave the solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this bloc like that:

```
if(c != null){
    if (!c.moveToFirst()) 
            return false;

        String existingName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Mode.NAME));

        return ContentValueDefaults.UNIQUE_NAME.equals(existingName);
} else {
     // return the boolean value if your cursor is null
}
```